# Integrating $\frac{1}{8z^3-1}$ over unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

So I need to integrate

$$\int_{\vert z \vert = 1} \frac{1}{8z^3-1}dz=\int_{\vert z \vert =1}\frac{1}{(2z-1)(4z^2+2z+1)}dz$$

Do I need to find the zeroes of both factors and calculate the residues at those points ? I know I have a a pole at $z=\frac{1}{2}$, and for the other one I can use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Factoring actually made this harder on yourself as $8z^3=1$ is much easier to solve for all three roots simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Note that if we want to find the zeroes of $4z^2+2z+1$, we can use the quadretic formula: $$z_{1,2}=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{-12}}{8}=\frac{-1\pm3i}{2}$$ Now, $z_1=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{3i}{2}$ is not inside of your contour, and neither is $\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{3i}{2}$, so you only care about the pole at $z=\frac{1}{2}$. One way to go at it is use the residue theorem as you've mentioned. Another way to go at it, is to define $g(z)=\frac{1}{4z^2+2z+1}$. This function has no poles inside your contour and hence analytic. By Cauchy's formula:$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{8z^3-1}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{g(z)}{2z-1}dz=\frac{1}{4\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{g(z)}{z-\frac{1}{2}}dz=g(\frac{1}{2})$$
So your integral is $g(\frac{1}{2})4\pi i$.

Comment: This makes so much sense, thank you !!

Comment: question, I used quadratic formula to factor $4z^2+2z+1$ and I get $-\frac{1}{4}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}i$

Comment: @anonymous This is correct